# Elmah not working with asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, exception, elmah

I've tried to use elmah with my asp.net site but whenever I try to go to http://localhost:port/elmah.axd I get resource not found exception. My web.config is given below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="elmah">
          <section name="security" requirePermission="false" 
                  type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
          <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" 
                  type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
          <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" 
                  type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
          <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" 
                  type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <elmah>
        <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
        <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" 
                 connectionStringName="elmah-sql" />
        <errorMail
                from="my@account"
                to="myself"
                subject="ERROR From Elmah:"
                async="true"
                smtpPort="587"
                smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com"
                userName="my@account"
                password="mypassword" />
      </elmah>

      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="elmah-sql" connectionString="data source=(sqlserver); 
               database=elmahdb;
             integrated security=false;User ID=user;Password=password"/>
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Elmah, Version=1.0.10617.0, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=null"/>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>

        <httpHandlers>
          <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
          <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" 
            type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, 
               System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                  PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" 
               type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, 
               System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" 
                 type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, 
               System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                    PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, 
                System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
      </system.web>

      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
          <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" 
                type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, 
               System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
          <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
          <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
        </modules>

        <handlers>
          <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
          <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
          <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
          <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
          <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" 
                preCondition="integratedMode" 
               type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, 
                    System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" 
            path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" 
               type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, 
                 System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" 
            verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" 
               type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, 
            System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" 
                       preCondition="integratedMode" 
               type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
        </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

EDIT: Elmah = (Error Logging Modules and Handlers)
http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: Aman: You are assuming everyone knows what is ELMAH. I have edited the question to provide the link. Correct it, if it is not the case.

Comment: I guess you might have to register the handler/module at IIS level, I guess for it to work.

Comment: See if this helps - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx

Comment: Thanks @shahkalpesh. I'm really overwhelmed with work! Though I thought this question may help others also and made it community wiki.

Comment: Weird but I tried the suggestions with no luck! Worst, when I tried to access `elmah.axd`, the IIS hangs.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try registering the Modules and Handlers in the sections "httphandlers" and "httpmodules" in the `<system.web>` section:

```
    <httpHandlers>
      ......
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
      .....

    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        .......
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
       .......
    </httpModules>
```

Comment: Yippe its working!!! It occurred to me also to put it there but I've not seen it in any online blogs solutions etc so I was bit sort of shy to do it.

Answer (score 153):

I just had a similar problem with Elmah not working in an IIS7 deployment. I found that I needed to register the Elmah Modules and Handlers in `system.web` AND `system.webServer`:

```
<system.web>
...
  <httpHandlers>
    ...
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    ...
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
    ...
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
    <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    ...
  </httpModules>
  ...
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    ...
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
    <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    ...
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    ...
    <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    ...
  </handlers>
<system.webServer>
```

Comment: For some reason, this got ELMAH working for me on a different server.  Which is odd, as it should be identical to ours, yet we just have system.webserver declarations.

Comment: for those of you cutting and pasting from system.web to system.webserver, make sure you add the name attribute in the handlers section.

Comment: Thanks, solved my issue, too!! I had defined a filter for 404s and it continued to log them ..

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. But is this a bug? `<system.web>` is supposed to be for IIS6 while `<system.webServer>` is for IIS7+ per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355261/whats-the-difference-between-system-web-and-system-webserver

Comment: @sid i think yes it's a bug in the nuget package - but not in anything else.

Answer (score 120):

*You may be need this one also*

```
<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
</elmah>
```

when you get

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

Comment: This did it for me after verifying eyesnz's post.

Comment: Yea but don't forget to secure that page via authentication. Otherwise anyone can read your logs.

Comment: well, Yes. 404 is "not found" but mostly when you fix 404 as marked answer you usually got 403.

Comment: you need to add under sectiongroup name="elmah"   **<section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>**

Comment: You need to add this after the </configSections> tag

Comment: You're a life safer. I always forget about this attribute lol.

Answer (score 12):

One way to get around it today is to use nuget.

Visual studio:menu->tools->library package manager->package manager console

```
install-package elmah
```

HTH

Comment: nuget is really making developers life easier.

Comment: Did just fine on my web.config

Answer (score 12):

This line was missing when I installed using NuGet (VS 2013, IIS 8.0):

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
 </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Adding it solved the 404 error problem.

Comment: This absolutely worked for me as well. Thanks Peter.

Comment: This was the fix for me, I am also on vs 2013, iis8.0, used nuget to install.

Comment: This fixed it for me in VS 2015 on localhost in debug after using nuget to install ELMAH.

Comment: I had this too. I've raised an issue with the project https://github.com/alexbeletsky/elmah-mvc/issues/89

Comment: Worked for me as well

Answer (score 9):

The nuget package does not add the following important lines to web.config resulting in 403 error.

```
<configuration>
  <elmah>  
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/app_data/elmah" />
  </elmah>
</configuration>
```

Also you may want to restrict the access to error logs by

```
<add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="/admin/elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Areas make sure that you have updated one of the appsetting key

Default

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
```

If you are an area as Admin

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="admin/elmah" />
```