# Elmah in Web Forms app - not working 'Place not found'

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I have installed elmah on an existing ASP.NET 4.5.1 web forms app by typing:

```
install-package elmah
```

in the nuget package manager.

It states I have to go to localhost/myapp/elmah.axd to see the log - but I get this error:

```
Place not found
```

I have found articles about this that, amongst other things state I must update both the system.web and system.webServer sections of web.config. The install-package already has done both of these however.
["Resource not found" error while accessing elmah.axd in ASP.NET MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120700/resource-not-found-error-while-accessing-elmah-axd-in-asp-net-mvc-project)

I just tried installing this package on a clean new web forms site - and it works fine.

How can I get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by copying the web.config from the new blank application I made.

I also needed to add this route:
routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");