# elmah.axd/stylesheet not found error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, elmah

I Just installed ELMAH 1.2.2 from nuget to my WebApi 2 (5.2.3) project. It logs errors but **elmah.axd's stylesheet doesn't load**. And WebApi shows the following error:

```
{
    "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://api.sample.dev/elmah.axd/stylesheet'.",
    "messageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'elmah.axd'."
}
```

I read some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1120700) but doesn't seems related to my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this error by preventing the WebApi's routing from catching requests to *.axd.

You can add the following line to your routing config.

```
httpConfig.Routes.IgnoreRoute("DynamicResources", "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Now you can access elmah.axd's stylesheet and have a well styled log report page.