# Getting started with Elmah?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I've read http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx and would like to use it in my mvc application; I'm running the MVC 2 preview.

My problem is, that when I follow instructions in article (providing dll and modifying web.config), I encounter an error when accessing http://localhost:62864/elmah.axd (ressource not found).

Any suggestions?

Any references to a good "get started" article on elmah?

Thanks,

Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might find the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933554/elmah-not-working-with-asp-net-site) question.

Comment: Yup!
"I found that I needed to register the Elmah Modules and Handlers in system.web AND system.webServer" helped me...
Thanks, Maurice!

Answer (score 0):

The [project page](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) on Google code has some links to some discussion groups (fifth box down on the right-side of the page. You might get more help there.

Andy