# Can't get ELMAH to works with ASP.NET MVC2 on IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, http-status-code-404, elmah

I try to use ELMAH on my ASP.NET MVC2 application, it works fine on the test server (Casini x86) while using the x86 version, but when I deploy it on the production server with the x86_64 version, I get a 404 error when I try to access "elmah.axd" and no errors are logged on IIS (but they are logged in Casini)

Here is my Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IronViper;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="IronViperEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.IronViper.csdl|res://*/Models.IronViper.ssdl|res://*/Models.IronViper.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IronViper;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
  </elmah>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <trace localOnly="false" pageOutput="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <httpWarmup>
      <requests>
        <add requestUrl="/" allowedResponseCodes="200-399" warmupContext="" sendMode="Asynchronous" />
      </requests>
    </httpWarmup>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The URL used on the production server is: http://xxxx/IronViperWebInterface/elmah.axd

and on Casini : http://localhost:xxxx/elmah.axd

I tried to change

```
<add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
```

to

```
<add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="IronViperWebInterface/elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
```

but that don't change anything.

I can't find the problem..

Any idea please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this might be your answer:

[Elmah not working with asp.net site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933554/elmah-not-working-with-asp-net-site/1175023#1175023)