# Error signalling in ELMAH not working with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, error-handling, elmah

My understanding is that raising an errorsignal should log my error or hit the custom HandleErrorWithELMAHAttribute class(taken from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961)) ,But it does neither.

I am using the HandleErrorWithElmah decorator for the controller in question.The error logging works when it comes to unhandled exceptions in the controller(I am explicitly calling Logexception and not using conditions mentioned in the second code block of  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961)). But the error signalling feature which is to be used for handled errors is keeping me baffled. How does error signalling work...Is it supposed to do something other than Logging...If so how can i use it log my handled exceptions?

This is the code i am using to signal handled errors

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Some Handled Error"));
```

And below are snippets of my settings in web config

```
  <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="elmah">
            <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        </sectionGroup>
     </configSections>


<elmah>
<security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Log" />
</elmah>



<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Elmah with .NET MVC and raising Elmah exceptions programmically works for me. I may be clutching a straws here but from looking at the fourth comment down on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC) on the Elmah site there are a couple of lines included in the Web.config that aren't in your example above.

It could be that you just didn't include the lines in your snippet, but I thought I'd throw it out there anyway

Comment: Thanks Phil...that solved the problem. It seems we need these tags when deploying to IIS7 which i was using. ELMAH's signals failed silently which made the problem more mysterious. A more detailed explanation on this was found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933554/elmah-not-working-with-asp-net-site#answer-1175023