# Elmah not working with gmail for MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, elmah

I am using ELMAH for my MVC 3 application with Gmail. I have used several references on how to do this, including [This StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933554/elmah-not-working-with-asp-net-site), which goes over multiple fixes

I am still unable to determine why I am not getting emails from elmah. I am attempting to test this by throwing a NullReferenceException in my code that I am calling.

My web.config looks like the following:

```
     <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false"  type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
     <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
      </pages>
      </system.web>
      <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="username@gmail.com" password="myPassword"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <elmah>
    <errorMail   from="fromAddress@gmail.com" to="toAddress@gmail.com" subject="Error" async="true" smtpPort="587"       useSsl="true"/>
    </elmah>
    <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

      <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"    type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
      <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd"      type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
    </handlers>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Any ideas on why this might not be working?

Comment: Stupid question but have to ask - have you checked Gmail's spam filter?  I often forget to look there but occasionally it can be aggressive.

Comment: No such thing as a stupid question! That being said, I checked, but no luck =( I am running out of ideas! Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:**  This may not be necessarily true looking at other ELMAH configurations, but you may want to try this anyways.  Also, I know that the enableSSL attribute on the system.net mail settings is new in .NET 4.0 - you might want to add `enableSSL=true` in that section as well since GMail does use SSL to connect.

It looks like you left your host configuration property and a few other settings out of your ELMAH settings for email when comparing your setup to those of other ELMAH configurations.  I don't think ELMAH looks at the system.net mail settings, but rather it's own errorMail tag

This:

```
<elmah>
    <errorMail 
      from="fromAddress@gmail.com"
       to="toAddress@gmail.com"
       subject="Error"
       async="true"
       smtpPort="587"
       useSsl="true"/>
    </elmah>
```

Should be changed to this:

```
<elmah>
    <errorMail 
      from="fromAddress@gmail.com"
       to="toAddress@gmail.com"
       subject="Error"
       async="true"
       smtpPort="587"
       useSsl="true"
       host="smtp.gmail.com"
       userName="username@gmail.com"
       password="myPassword"/>
    </elmah>
```

Comment: In <errorMail>, set the smtpPort attribute to "0". Doing so will cause ELMAH to use the port defined per the <system.net> settings instead.

Comment: should the host attribute be smtpServer?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what part of this helped, but I struggled for a whole day trying to get elmah to send email thru SES and using your settings worked for me!  Thanks!

Comment: The Elmah mail settings worked for me. I have a web app and a windows service that I use Elmah for. Neither we relaying the e-mail. I added the mail settings to the elmah configuration node in both and they both started working.