# ELMAH not logging errors except for 404's

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I can't get ELMAH to log errors to my `AppData` folder for any exceptions except for `404` errors.  I'm not sure what the problem could be.  I'm guessing it's because I have `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml">`, but I've tried doing what's recorded [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/5936867#5936867) and haven't had any luck.  Here's my web.config (at least anything critical to using ELMAH):

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
  <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
</sectionGroup>

<appSettings>
  <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="Programmers" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
  <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
</appSettings>

<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
</httpModules>

<modules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>

<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data"/>
</elmah>
```

Here's my `FilterConfig.cs`:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorLoggerFilter());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

And my Custom Elmah Handler:

```
public class ElmahHandleErrorLoggerFilter : System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter
{

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //Log only handled exceptions, because all others will be caught by ELMAH
        if (context.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: How does this behave if you remove the `ElmahHandleErrorLoggerFilter`?

Comment: It still does the same thing.  Nothing is being logged.

Comment: Try adding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` [Also have a look at this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/933586/1644019)

Comment: What kind of exception is throw and where? By the way: 1. you don't need the `ElmahHandleErrorLoggerFilter` and `HandleErrorAttribute` since `Elmah.MVC` injects one if `disableHandleErrorFilter` is `false`. 2. `Error.cshtml` is not accessible from browsers (try accessing /Views/Shared/Error.cshtml from your browser and see what happens). You must use an HTML file outside the views folder.

Answer (score 1):

Basically ELMAH will log all unhandled exceptions by default, also it will log all requests as well.

You even don't need any Log Filters.

All that you need is just to add **`runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`** to ELMAH **`modules`** section:

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

That will allows ELMAH to process all requests and log all errors.