# Jquery call wcf service giving 200 Parser Error

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, jquery, jsonp

I'm new to WCF world. i'm having a solution which contains Web App(which has JQuery Ajax call to WCF services application which is another project in the solution. After 2 days of working(cracking) i'm in a state which i able pass request and get response [image]

but while try to show that in alert gives me 200 parser Error.[image]

Any help will be highly appreciate

Further Ref

```
$.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    type: 'GET', //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                    url: 'http://localhost:61057/Service1.svc/GetCustomer', // Location of the service
                    dataType: 'jsonp', //Expected data format from server
                    success: function (data) {//On Successfull service call
                        ServiceSucceeded(data);
                    },
                    error: function () { ServiceFailed(Data); } // When Service call fails
                });
```

Web.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="FIN.Services.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:61057/service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="FIN.Services.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior">
          <identity>
            <dns value="locahost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

service interface :

```
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        string GetCustomer();
```

Comment: Since you are jumping ports, take a look here:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234599/cors-support-within-wcf-rest-services/7770206#7770206

Answer (score 0):

If you need no argument, add following in your ajax call ..

data: "{}",

Answer (score 0):

You are using  **jsonp**,means you want to call cross domain service.
For cross domain service you url should be like below

**http://localhost:61057/Service1.svc/GetCustomer?callback=?**

and also you have to make some changes in web.config

Check out the following link for complete example

[Calling cross domain service in wcf](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2012/02/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html)