# call to odata webservice returns 401 using jaydata.js

Tags: iis, odata, cors, jaydata

I make a call to an odata webservice using jaydata.js but it returns 401 Unauthorized.

Even if browse to the service and authenticate first manually in a second browser tab, is still get 401 in the first tab.

This is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/datajs-1.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jaydata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/DynamicsNav70.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jaydataproviders/oDataProvider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        nav = new NAV.NAV({
            name: 'oData', oDataServiceHost: 'http://XXX.cloudapp.net:7048/DynamicsNav70/OData',
            user: "XXX",
            password: "XXX"
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            nav.Customers.forEach(function (customer) {
                var item = "<li ><a href=#>@name</a></li>".replace("@name", customer.Name);
                $('#customers').append(item);
            });
        });

    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Customers</h1>
    <ul id="customers"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the info from by browser :

```
Request URL:http://XXX.cloudapp.net:7048/DynamicsNav70/OData/Customers
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en,nl;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, maxdataserviceversion, origin, dataserviceversion
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:XXX.cloudapp.net:7048
Origin:http://localhost:50793
Referer:http://localhost:50793/jaydata.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:0
Date:Thu, 06 Jun 2013 14:43:12 GMT
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate:Negotiate
```

I'm a total noob in this matter, so any advice for a solution or better understanding of the problem could be helpfull

Comment: I think you experience this issue because of the CORS http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/the-cors/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723088/401-response-for-cors-request-in-iis-with-windows-auth-enabled

Comment: this is due to CORS, I solved it with [THIS][1] reply from SO.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7770206/2068563