# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, restful-authentication, basichttpbinding

While trying to invoke a RESTful service(i have used UserNameAuthenticator from this sample for RESTful service [Adding basic HTTP auth to a WCF REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715752/adding-basic-http-auth-to-a-wcf-rest-service)) from my web client application am getting an error like

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic Realm'.
```

Client CS code

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
EndpointAddress address = new  EndpointAddress("http://localhost:12229/RestServiceImpl.svc");
ChannelFactory<RestService.IRestServiceImpl> factory =
new ChannelFactory<RestService.IRestServiceImpl>(binding, address);
RestService.IRestServiceImpl channel = factory.CreateChannel();
channel.GetStudent();
```

Client Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:12229/RestServiceImpl.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ExternalSystemsService_v1Interface"
          contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl"
          name="ExternalSystemsService_v1Port" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ExternalSystemsService_v1Interface"
                         closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                         sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536"
                         maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and RESTful service Web.config

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
          </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl">
        <endpoint name="ExternalSystemsService_v1Port" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ExternalSystemsService_v1Interface" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SecureRESTSvcTestBehavior">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="RESTfulSecuritySH.CustomUserNameValidator, RESTfulSecuritySH" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You aren't using your `.config` at all when you construct the `BasicHttpBinding`. So for Auth, all you have done is set the authentication protocol, BUT you haven't set the credentials you wish to authenticate against. Either use the `ChannelFactory` constructor that takes a binding name as a `string`, or set up your credentials in your instanticated `BasicHttpBinding`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that sticks out to me is that in your Client CS Code you programmatically set the **transport's** client credential type:

```
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
```

But in both the client and server configuration file you set the **message** client credential type.  Notice how the transport element's clientCredentialType attribute is set to "None" and message element's clientCredentialType is set to "UserName":

```
<transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
<message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
```

I always try to get it working in development with security turned off and then slowly turn it back on.

Also is this a new development project?  I was curious why you're using WCF over ASP.NET Web API for a RESTful service.

Comment: The `.config` would be completely ignored, since the OP is instanciating the `BasicHttpBinding` himself, as opposed to using the factory method from the default constructor for the `ChannelFactory`.