# Separate httpmodule(s) in web.config for a WCF web service within an ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, web-config

I've got a WCF (RESTful) web service within an ASP.NET website project.  The service resides at /WebServices/Registration.svc.  I'm trying to create a custom BasicAuthenticationModule httpModule to handle Basic Auth as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4729555/291323, but the module is being used for my entire website, which I do not want.

I tried using the  tag to define the module for ONLY the service, but couldn't get it to work.  I tried setting the path to both "WebServices/Registration.svc" as well as just "WebServices".

Is there a better way to register an httpModule to affect ONLY a WCF webservice within a website project?

TIA for any assistance!

Comment: I've come across the same situation. I want HttpModule enabled for all my WCF webservices, but not the website itself. Any idea?