# web.config system.webServer Vs system.web

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I created a Handler if I add Handler in `<system.web>` it works fine for IIS 6.0 but doesn't work on IIS 7.0, and Vice Versa if I add in `<system.webServer>` . Is there any thing common I can do so that it should work for both

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between <system.web> and <system.webServer>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355261/whats-the-difference-between-system-web-and-system-webserver)

Comment: This link maybe helps you: http://arcware.net/use-a-single-web-config-for-iis6-and-iis7/ To give you a real answer we would need more information like which exception do you get etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just go with Martin's comment or http://arcware.net/2008/04/08/use-a-single-web-config-for-iis6-and-iis7/

Note: The link above is not working.  Looks like he nuked all his old blog posts, but the page can still be accessed [via the wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120712154258/http://arcware.net/2008/04/08/use-a-single-web-config-for-iis6-and-iis7).

Comment: The link works fine if you add the `archive` subdomain. An easier option is to just use the same URL Martin used: http://arcware.net/use-a-single-web-config-for-iis6-and-iis7/.