# ASP.net Handler Mapping Not Recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, handler, httphandler

I am having trouble migrating a website from a Windows 2003 server to a windows 2012R2 server. Basic connectivity to the site is up, the site accesses the database okay, and I can log in and navigate through the pages.

The problem I am running into is when I try to generate a report. Initially, IIS could not find the Microsoft Forms application for version 8.0.0.0. I installed Microsoft Web Forms 2005, and moved on to the next error, which is where I am stuck.

I have found many sites with these instructions:
http://ericphan.net/blog/2008/12/8/reservedreportviewerwebcontrolaxd-not-found.html#comments-outer-wrapper

And have configured my own setup accordingly (accounting for different versions)

[image: Handler Configuration]

But, when I navigate to the website, I see

[image: Handler Error]

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved through two solutions.

First, I followed this guidance.

[What's the difference between <system.web> and <system.webServer>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355261/whats-the-difference-between-system-web-and-system-webserver/355296#355296)

(As you can see, the topic isn't related to my error, so I didn't find it without additional guidance.)

Once that was done, I also had to switch from `Integrated` to `Classic` pipeline mode, presumably because I was migrating from a much older version of IIS and Windows Server.

Problem solved =D